# Sass vs LESS - include css class

Tags: css, sass, less

In LESS you can do that:

```
.my-class {
    color:blue;
}

.my-other-class {
    .my-class;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

In Sass it can be done with `@extend`:

```
.my-other-class {
        @extend .my-class;
        font-size:14px;
}
```

But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560170/including-another-class-in-scss#comment24241967_9595542), in comment to main text, [MartinAnsty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1239254/martinansty) says that it might not work with `@media` directives.
So functionality of `@extend` in Sass and mixins in LESS are fully equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work, Martin means the mediaquery will also be extended, if class have them. So if .my-class has got media query max-width 500{ color: blue }, and min-width 600 { color: green } you have to remeber that it will be executed in extend.