# Why is SASS producing so many CSS rules?

Tags: sass

I write my CSS in SASS file and compile it using CodeKit into a CSS document. I've continuously been mystified as to how exactly SASS is compiling my CSS rules, specifically when I attempt to track down compiled CSS rules that seem to not have a corresponding SASS rule.

I have a SASS file with the following rule, which is not nested:

```
.interviewprep .products .module img {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 1em 0 0;
        width: 10em;
}
```

But when I look at my compiled css file and I search for ".interviewprep .products .module img," I find this giant css rule:

```
.interviewprep .products .module img,.interviewprep .products .bluemodule img
.interviewprep .products .page-template-page-1col-php .customersspeak .speak_small p img,
.page-template-page-1col-php .customersspeak .speak_small .interviewprep .products p img,
.interviewprep .products .videowidget img, .interviewprep .products .page-id-2310
.pricebox img, .page-id-2310 .interviewprep .products .pricebox img, .interviewprep     
.products .page-id-2406 .pricebox img, .page-id-2406 .interviewprep .products .pricebox 
img, ..interviewprep .products .excel a[title="pdf"] img, .excel .interviewprep .products 
a[title="pdf"] img, .interviewprep .products .excel a[title="pdf2"] img,
.excel .interviewprep .products a[title="pdf2"] img, .interviewprep .products div.wpcf7 
img, .interviewprep .products .mycourses form img, .mycourses .interviewprep .products 
form img {
   float: left;
   margin: 0 1em 0 0;
   width: 10em; 
}
```

Now, at first I thought, is the compiling process smart enough to go and find all of the rules in my sass document that use the 3 rules:

```
float: left;
margin: 0 1em 0 0;
width: 10em;
```

and lump them all together in the outputted css? But this isn't the case. When I search "margin: 0 1em 0 0;" in both my SASS and my CSS file, the only element that is using that rule is the un-nested rule from my SASS file (as above) ".interviewprep .products .module img"

Even MORE mystifying to me is that other than the first element of ".interviewprep .products .module img," NONE of those elements in that giant line in my compiled css are written anywhere in my SASS file. None of them are written in a unnested format, nor are there any combinations of nested elements that would produce those "compiled" elements.

For example, nowhere in my SASS file is that second element from the giant css line: ".interviewprep .products .bluemodule img"

That rule is nowhere to be found in an unnested format, nor are there any combinations of nested formats that would produce that rule, as in:

```
.interviewprep .prouducts {
    .bluemodule {
        img {
        }
     }
}
```

So WHERE could all of those rules possibly be coming from? I've done a ton of back and forth trying to track down all of these rules -- my css file is FILLED with them. I've taken away a TON of unnecessary nesting, but still I have way too many rules in my css.

Comment: I can't repro this problem. http://sassmeister.com/gist/8800f9e4144f96feadc5 You'll need to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help you.

Comment: Have you tried compiling your css with the `line_numbers` option turned on?  This will tell you where in your sass file a specific rule is defined.  See here:  http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#line_numbers-option

Comment: Total guess, but perhaps a stray curly brace is actually nesting something? It might be helpful if you provided the entire SASS file.

Comment: Part of the debugging process involves stripping the problem down to the smallest possible amount of code that *reproduces the problem*.  There's not enough code here to do that.  Once you do this, the answer will be obvious.

Comment: This looks like the result of using `@extend`. I'd start my search there.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone, and apologies I did not post all of the code here to help in seeking answers. I suppose since my problem itself was an insane amount of code being produced, I did not want to post that insane amount of code here. Anyways, coreyward, thanks for that push in the right direction. This was indeed caused by "not the nest use" of @extend. I will answer my own question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by "not-so-careful" use of SASS's @extend feature, which forevermore I will use with more care. A very important thing to keep in mind when using @extend is that extending a selector will extend ALL the occurrences of the selector. This is somewhat hard to wrap one's head around at first (at least it was for me). For example, these SASS rules:

```
.foo {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bar {
  @extend .foo;
} 

.qux .foo {
  color: red;
}
```

Will produce these CSS rules:

```
.foo, .bar {
  font-weight: bold; }

.qux .foo, .qux .bar {
  color: red; }
```

From the SASS documentation: @extend works by inserting the extending selector (.bar) anywhere in the stylesheet that the extended selector (.foo) appears.

I suppose the trick is to not use @extend for elements that will be used many times in your SASS file. So, if you have 30 rules for p tags, don't use "@extend p" in your SASS styles or it will produce ton of likely unnecessary p rules.