# Reusable Block with Nested Elements - SCSS

Tags: css, sass, mixins

Say I have two unordered lists in one stylesheet. Both should be using the same styling, but both are nested in different parent elements:

```
#foo{
  position:absolute;
  ...
  ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    li{
      color:red;
      ...
    }
  }
}

#bar{
  position:relative;
  ...
  ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    li{
      color:red;
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to create something similar to a Rails' partial, where a single block of code can be reused / rendered inside different parent elements?

Comment: Can't you just apply a class name to both lists and style the class accordingly?

Comment: @pete I actually ended up doing just that, but I still want to see if SCSS provides a programmatic way to achieve what I want (perhaps allow passing *args inside such nested blocks).

Comment: Why you don't use `mixin`?

Comment: @alirezasafian can't seem to find anything on using mixins for nested styling. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check [this](https://gist.github.com/alireza-safian/3f00a687a50c076dad09)

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Anything at all?  There are a lot of examples in the documentation.  You really should be doing a little bit more research before you ask questions.

Comment: Tried http://sass-lang.com/guide's, `mixins`, `nesting` and `inheritance` sections. Could not find what I was looking for in there. I'm sure there are a lot of "examples in the documentation" and SO but I had no idea what to search by.

Comment: My point is that you didn't *try* anything.  You looked at mixins, but did you try writing one?  To see if maybe nesting was supported in it?

Comment: @cimmanon yes, I've used simple mixins with and then called them inside a single element with `@include`, but I could not figure out how to use a mixin with nested elements inside. You are probably right, I should have "played" with SASS some more before asking the question, but I was not sure which SASS method would work best in my case.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Solutions:

1-**Mixins** [Link](https://gist.github.com/alireza-safian/3f00a687a50c076dad09)

```
@mixin ul-style ()
{
   ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    li{
      color:red;
    }
  }
}

#foo{
  position:absolute;
  @include ul-style();
}

#bar{
  position:relative;
  @include ul-style();
}
```

2-**Inheritance** [Link](https://gist.github.com/alireza-safian/22f0d37d4f0bb6042c4d)

```
.ul-style
{
  ul
  {
    list-style-type:none;
    li{
      color:red;
    }  }

}

#foo{
  position:absolute;
  @extend .ul-style;

}

#bar{
  position:relative;
  @extend .ul-style;
}
```

Comment: Yep, #1 is exactly what I needed! Was not sure which SCSS method can be used to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks! I just came up with a dynamic combination of the both: Extend from Mixin Check my answer at the duplicate question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66259322/11155364