# How to apply a bootstrap class to every same HTML element in css file?

Tags: html, css, class, attributes

How to apply a bootstrap class to every same HTML element in css file? for example, if I want to apply a bootstrap class "pull-right" to every  tag I require to put class name inside a class attribute in every  tag presently.
is there any way to right once and effect anywhere in html file?

Comment: You can use jQuery or pure JavaScript `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` to select all elements in your HTML page and apply the class to it, but the question is if you want to select all elements why not use a CSS selector for that? in pure CSS it's kinda tricky to apply a class to a selector though, easier to copy the content of your bootstrap css class.

Comment: This is why it is better to *write CSS* rather than sticking presentational class names into HTML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use asterix `*` to apply styles to all tags. But you can't apply styles of `class` to elements in clear css. You can do this using `scss` http://sass-lang.com/ or `less css`http://lesscss.org/

here is an example in `less css`

```
* {
    .pull-right;
}
```

Comment: Hi, And how we can do the same with SASS?

Comment: Here you have examples how to do this with SASS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560170/including-another-class-in-scss